# How do you break into Visual Studio's debugger right when you start debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

WinDbg, ntsd, and other Debugging Tools For Windows (dbgeng) debuggers will break into the debugger command prompt immediately after attaching to a running application or kernel, or soon after startup for a newly launched app or a rebooting system's kernel.

I use this ["initial breakpoint"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/initial-breakpoint) routinely to set breakpoints, load debug symbols, and otherwise prepare for debugging, but Visual Studio doesn't have an initial breakpoint, at least not by default.

So, how *can* I make VS 2019 break into its debugger right when I start a debugging session? If it's not built in to VS, is there a VS extension that will do it for me?

Comment: Start with F10 rather than F5?..

Comment: Debug > Step Into.  None of the reasons you listed require that, it can all be done up front before you start debugging.

Comment: @GSerg unfortunately Step Over/Into (F10/F11) don't solve the problem since I still have to break in first.

Comment: @HansPassant VS loads all the symbols by default, which is terrible for slow connections. You can make it load only your pre-approved symbols by default, but then what if you want to break in on a DLL that isn't pre-approved? In ntsd the answer would be: wait for the initial break, `bu dllname!symbol` and maybe `.reload dllname.dll`, then `g`. There's no equivalent in VS if there is no initial break, unless you count frantically hitting Ctrl-Alt-Break.

Comment: Hard to make sense of that, it only downloads symbols once.  Make sure you setup the symbol cache directory correctly.  If it is slow finding out that symbols are not available then just spike the cache once and turn off the symbol server.

Comment: Every day I am likely to get a symbol cache miss on every DLL that gets loaded into the process, which in VS's default settings would mean downloading on the order of 1 GB of private symbols from the symbol server. That's because I build a relatively small part of a large application, and I regularly test against new continuous integration builds of the app and of the third-party apps and libraries it interfaces with. For that reason "just wait for the cache" or "manually prefetch into the cache" isn't a viable option.